# Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2013 send as issue

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2010

My customer have 4 mail address. The default mail address A and other B,C,D address.

The setting of the Exchange server is address A have send as rights to B,C,D.

The settings of Outlook client is address A is default address and B,C,D are alternative address.

The mail client works fine on pass days but in one day. The send out messages of address B,C,D dropped into address A's sent box and the message's header will have "address A sent on behalf of address B" (Normally behavior is the message will drop to the co-responding address's sent box). The issues come and gone suddenly.  Please help to advise. Thanks.

Samuel Chu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe administrator assigned the send on behalf permission to A on B/C/D.

Comment: Thanks for your help Niko. But I've check the permission via EAC. The permissions are correct.